# Adding Apollo Mutations to a composable in Vue

Tags: vue.js, apollo, vue-composition-api, vue-apollo

I am encapsulating some Apollo mutations in a Composable in Vue to allow the functionality to be reused in multiple components however for one instance, I need to know what the parameters of the mutation were so I can create the update function.

When I try to wrap the mutation in a function, I receive the following error

> Error: Apollo client with id default not found. Use provideApolloClient() if you are outside of a component setup.

This has not come up with any of the other queries / mutations in the composable so it seems that useMutation is losing scope within a function

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export function useComposable() {
  const TEAMS_QUERY = gql`
    query Teams {
      teams {
        nodes {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const leaveTeam = ({ teamId, userId }) => {
    const { mutate } = useMutation(
      DELETE_TEAM_MEMBERSHIP,
      () => ({
        update(cache, { data: { deleteTeamMembership } }) {
          // use the function params here to update the cache
          let data = cache.readQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY });
          data = {
            ...data.teams
            nodes: data.teams.nodes.filter(
              (team) => team.id !== teamId
            )
          };
          cache.writeQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY, data });
        }
      })
    );
    return mutate({ teamId, userId });
  };

  return {
    leaveTeam
  };
}
```

I have re-written my function to the following (as recommended by the error) which works as expected (using the apollo provider from setup)

```js
export function useComposable() {
  const TEAMS_QUERY = gql`
    query Teams {
      teams {
        nodes {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const leaveTeam = ({ teamId, userId }) => {
    const { mutate } = provideApolloClient(apollo)(() => useMutation(
      DELETE_TEAM_MEMBERSHIP,
      () => ({
        update(cache, { data: { deleteTeamMembership } }) {
          // use the function params here to update the cache
          let data = cache.readQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY });
          data = {
            ...data.teams
            nodes: data.teams.nodes.filter(
              (team) => team.id !== teamId
            )
          };
          cache.writeQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY, data });
        }
      })
    ));
    return mutate({ teamId, userId });
  };

  return {
    leaveTeam
  };
}
```

I could also have done this (which works in this context) which also works as expected (note: not inside a function but directly inside the composable)

```js
export function useComposable() {
  const TEAMS_QUERY = gql`
    query Teams {
      teams {
        nodes {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const { mutate: leaveTeam } = useMutation(
    DELETE_TEAM_MEMBERSHIP,
    () => ({
      update(cache, { data: { deleteTeamMembership } }) {
        // use the function params here to update the cache
        let data = cache.readQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY });
        data = {
          ...data.teams
          nodes: data.teams.nodes.filter(
            (team) => team.id !== teamId
          )
        };
        cache.writeQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY, data });
      }
    })
  );

  return {
    leaveTeam
  };
}
```

However I'd like to know why the scope function is considered outside of the Vue Apollo context and needs it to be provided if anyone has an explanation?

The composable may then used within my sfc like

```
<script setup>
import { useComposable } from './useComposable';

const { leaveTeam } = useComposable();

// mocked data
const user = { id: 0, name: 'My Name' };

const teams = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Team 1' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Team 2' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Team 3' }
];
</script>

<template>
  <section class="teams-list">
    <h1>Admin {{ user.name }}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="team in teams" :key="team.id">
        {{ team.name }}
        <button @click="leaveTeam({ teamId: team.id, userId: user.id })">
          Leave Team
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <section>
</template>
```

Thanks

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown where you use this composable

Comment: Added more context

Comment: Note: I have rewritten this in my actual application to use the params from the `update()`  function to avoid needing to wrap this particular case in a function but the question still stands for any useQuery or useMutation wrapped in a function (I have needed it in my components as well)

Comment: Thanks, looks legit, needs to be debugged. Probably the problem is in `apollo` var.

Comment: what's maybe not obvious is that if i return a mutation directly (ie not inside a function) it works quite happily without providing the addition apollo context - i'll update the example to show this

Comment: I see. As a rule of thumb, composables are supposed to be called in the body of comp setup, directly or not, any other usage needs to be confirmed and depends on the way a composable is implemented. Things like `useMutation` that depend on some application-specific instance are implemented with `provide`/`inject` and strictly limited to the usage in setup. You need to create `mutate` in the body of useComposable and call it inside leaveTeam and pass params to `update` somehow, I don't deal with Appolo much so can't help with the specifics

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes sense (but is a bit magic) and definitely tracks with the approach I've taken since this post. So the useX composables from apollo should be used directly in my composable and the resultant mutate (or result from useQuery, etc) called from the functions. The only real time you might need to use provideApolloClient is if you're creating the mutation or lazy query dynamically in the function

Comment: Consider posting a self-answer if you solved it, may help somebody else, especially since this is low-profile topic

Comment: Okay - good idea. Hopefully it's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a composable to encapsulate apollo functionality (I've found this especially useful to have the mutations with update functions alongside the queries they affect to maintain state between them), it seems like the following rules are useful.

- Create all queries and mutations up front, directly in your composable - the resultant `mutate()` function can be called directly, passing any variables required, from within your component using your composable

`useComposable.js`

```js
export function useComposable() {
  const TEAMS_QUERY = gql`query Teams {
    teams {
      nodes {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }`;

  const { mutate } = () => useMutation(
    DELETE_TEAM_MEMBERSHIP,
    () => ({
      update(cache, _, { variables: { teamId } }) {
        // use the function params here to update the cache
        let data = cache.readQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY });
        data = {
          ...data.teams
          nodes: data.teams.nodes.filter(
            (team) => team.id !== teamId
          )
        };
        cache.writeQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY, data });
      }
    })
  );

  return {
    mutate
  };
}
```

`Component.vue`

```
const team = { id: 1 };
const user = { id: 1 };

const { mutate } = useComposable();

mutate({
  teamId: team.id,
  userId: user.id
});
```

- call the resultant `mutate()` from a function if you need to wrap the functionality

```js
export function useComposable() {
  const TEAMS_QUERY = gql`
    query Teams {
      teams {
        nodes {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const { mutate } = () => useMutation(
    DELETE_TEAM_MEMBERSHIP,
    () => ({
      update(cache, _, { variables: { teamId } }) {
        // use the function params here to update the cache
        let data = cache.readQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY });
        data = {
          ...data.teams
          nodes: data.teams.nodes.filter(
            (team) => team.id !== teamId
          )
        };
        cache.writeQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY, data });
      }
    })
  );

  const leaveTeam = ({ teamId, userId }) => {
    // some other functionality
    return mutate({ teamId, userId });
  };


  return {
    leaveTeam
  };
}
```

- If you need to create a `useLazyQuery` or `useMutation` in a function (because you're creating a dynamic mutation, for example), use `provideApolloProvider` with your apollo provider that you set up in your application initialisation.

```js
import apollo from '@/plugins/apollo.js';

export function useComposable() {
  const TEAMS_QUERY = gql`
    query Teams {
      teams {
        nodes {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const leaveTeam = ({ teamId, userId }) => {
    const { mutate } = provideApolloClient(apollo)(() => useMutation(
      gql`mutation LeaveTeam($teamId: Int!, $userId: Int!) {
        leaveTeam(input: { teamId: $teamId, userId: $userId }) {
          team {
            id
          }
        }
      }`,
      () => ({
        update(cache, { data: { deleteTeamMembership } }) {
          // use the function params here to update the cache
          let data = cache.readQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY });
          data = {
            ...data.teams
            nodes: data.teams.nodes.filter(
              (team) => team.id !== teamId
            )
          };
          cache.writeQuery({ query: TEAMS_QUERY, data });
        }
      })
    ));
    return mutate({ teamId, userId });
  };


  return {
    leaveTeam
  };
}
```